# Windows 10 guest on ESXI 6.5 cannot find disk driver

Tags: vmware, esxi

My Windows 10 Pro guest fails to install on ESXI 6.5 as it cannot find disk drivers.

I've tried calculating/comparing the checksum of my ISO and re-uploading, as I understood similar issues are often caused by corrupt ISOs, but that didn't help.

I'm using standard settings with 2 vCPUs, 4GB RAM, 2 disks.

Answer (score 1):

As SCSI controller, `LSI Logic SAS` instead of `LSI Logic Parallel` should be chosen. 
Then the Windows 10 installation will find the disk(s) and installation can proceed.

[image]